# How to add two different ID with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using an Ajax function for show the auto suggestions for search field. But, I've to search field on the same page. So, when I am trying to use this then one is work and another one isn't. It's because Both of those are using couple of same ID and Class. I style them with CSS for different width and height.

Can anyone please help me know how may I add one more ID and Class on the below code for each field?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#email").keyup(function() { 
        var searchid = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'type=' + searchid;
        if (searchid != ' ') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "type_process.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#result").html(html).show();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;    
    });

    $(document).click(function(e) { 

        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        if (! $clicked.hasClass("get_types")) {
            jQuery("#result").fadeOut(); 
        }
    });

    $('#email').click(function(){
        jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
    });

});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: Are you trying to add more than 1 ID to a HTML element? That's not possible...

Comment: Are you using twice same selector? That isn't standard compliant. A id should be unique.Here is when classes come.
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Comment: Yes, That's why I want to use another ID but I don't know how to add another ID on the above code on every places

Comment: or use descendant selectors. make them classes instead of IDs and wrap both in an element with an id, different for each. Shared code uses `$('.myclass')` selector and search box specific code (or css) uses `$('#firstID').find('.myclass')` or `$('#secondID').find('.myclass')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select 2 element (or more) you can refer to a single one by specifing the element index.

```
$('.item').eq(0); // return the first element in a collection with class '.item'
```

or

```
$('.item').eq(1); // return second element in a collection with class '.item'
```

BTW, you should avoid having elements with the same ID in the DOM

Comment: If I write like this way: `$('#email, #message')` then does it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select lots of differents elements, use a Class tag instead.

Mark all your elements with the same class, like: `class="mySelectorClass"` and then, use a jquery selector:

```
$(".mySelectorClass").each(function(index,value){
    // ... your code for each element goes here!
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/